# Get the upper bound of convex hull as a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, convex-hull

[image]

The above figure figure shows a plot of the following functions:

- convexHull in red
- boundary in blue and
- scatter as purple points.

I want to create a function which will return 'y' for each 'x' assuming the convexHull as the Mathematical function.

Since there are 2 points corresponding to each x, the one with higher y value must be taken.

Comment: Evaluate both the `y` corresponding to each `x` and take the max

Comment: @Daniel no I havent. I found the function convexHull for matlab. It returned the index numbers of the points that I joined to obtain the convexhull as shown in the figure.

Comment: Try the next steps as well 2) Identify the leftmost and rightmost points. Use them to split the convex hull into an upper an lower part. The upper part is the one which contains the largest y value. 3) Use interp2 with linear interpolation to get the y value for arbitrary x values. Give it a try, when you don't know how to proceed put the code you got so far into your question and explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to compute y for x is to run a loop over the convex hull edges. If the vertical line positioned at x intersects the edge, find the y-coordinate of the intersection. At the end, output the maximum of such y-values. Some code with comments:

```
vx = [3 7 4 8 5 9 2 6 5 3];   % test data
vy = [2 4 1 3 2 5 2 6 5 4];   % test data
cvx = convhull(vx, vy);
X = vx(cvx); Y = vy(cvx);     % boundary of convex hull

x = 4.2;                      % test point
y = min(vy);                  % y starts at minimal value of all y-coords
for (i=1:numel(cvx)-1)
    if sign(X(i)-x) ~= sign(X(i+1)-x)     % if x is between X(i) and X(i+1)
        yc = Y(i+1)*(X(i)-x)/(X(i)-X(i+1)) + Y(i)*(x-X(i+1))/(X(i)-X(i+1));  
        y = max(y, yc);       % compare to linear interpolant yc, take larger
    end
end

hold on
plot(vx, vy, 'o')            
plot(X, Y)
plot(x, y, 'r*')
hold off
```

Output:

[image: convex]